# React-art for bower in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs

I can't get **react-art** in **bower.json** in *Visual Studio 2015*. However, I can get it in **package.json**.

**Package.json:**

As a result, I don't see **React-art** in the wwwroot\lib folder and the react-art not working.

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8",
    "react": "0.13.3",
    "react-art": "0.13.0"
  }
}
```

**bower.json**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you've got it package.json is because you've installed a npm package of react-art, not a bower one (which isn't available). But if you're using Browserify, you'll be to use it with the following command

```
var reactArt = require('react-art');
```